# Beginner in UI Automation unable to locate a dropdown element. Dropdown is static & has only 3 options

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

HTML Code for the drop down with 3 constant values:

```
<div class="a-popover-inner" style="height: auto; overflow-y: auto; min-width: 107px; width: auto;">
<ul id="3_dropdown_combobox" class="a-nostyle a-list-link" aria-multiselectable="false" role="listbox" tabindex="-1">
    <li class="a-dropdown-item status-option" role="option" tabindex="0">
    <li class="a-dropdown-item status-option" role="option" tabindex="0">
        <a class="a-dropdown-link a-active" data-value="{"stringVal":"Active"}" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1"> Active </a>
    </li>
    <li class="a-dropdown-item status-option" role="option" tabindex="0">
</ul>
```

Tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='status-select']/span/span"));
```

Result:

```
Able to click/select the dropdown successfully
```

But Unable to further select a specific dropdown

Try1:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*a[@data-value={'stringVal':'Active'}]")).click();
Result1:InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
```

Try2:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='status-select']/span/span"));
Result3: count = element.size(); // prints count as 1
//so cant get elements[element.count-1];
```

Try3:

```
 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("3_dropdown_combobox")));
      select.selectByVisibleText("Expired");
Result3:
```

Try4:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='3_dropdown_combobox']/li[2]/a")).click();
(or)
java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("3_dropdown_combobox"));elements.size();
```

Result4: console does nothing for >10min. I stop the execution

Please Guide me on what is correct way to select 2nd/3rd dropdown options

Comment: Could you add the html?

Comment: Is it possible to share a link to the page with that dropdown?

Comment: I cannot share the page as its still an internal link. All 3 dropdown options are static,simple & visible,clickable                       (HTML code is added at the top)

Comment: @Priya instead of posting a *"thank you"* answer you should "accept" the answer you found helpful, adding what specifically you did to solve the problem (as you did in your "answer")..

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("status-select")));
select.selectByIndex(1); //Selects the 2nd option in the dropdown list
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion Error: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"

Comment: I'm afraid `Select` would not handle the case.

Comment: Thanks for your time Tidus,Alecxe @ alecxe: Can you suggest how else can I Select the 2nd/3rd option in drop down please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to click the `Active` link this should work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="3_dropdown_combobox"]/li[2]/a")).click();
```

I tried doing

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="3_dropdown_combobox"]/li[2]/a")).getText();
```

and got the word `Active` as expected.

Try to see if the link takes you to the correct location

Comment: I have already tried this ("Try:4"). I am not understanding why console goes blank nor timesout nor throws error. Just blank for more than 10min+. Then I stop the execution by closing the browser.. Any idea why?

Comment: @Priya It should work for you. Where does that link suppose to take you to? Instead of click try to do getText() and see if you get the word `Active`. If you do get the text than your xpath is correct